# Reusable HttpClient instance vs static variable (Heavily used in multiple threads)?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, static, task, httpclient

I currently have an instance variable of a `HttpClient` which is used in an instance method to download an image. The method is always called in a `Task.Run()`.
This method can be called thousands of times in a minute and doesn't crash or produce any errors. But I just wanted to know what benefits, if any, there would be if I switched to a `static HttpClient`, apart from perhaps being more thread safe.

Here is some code for context:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); // Make this static?

// Always called in a Task.Run(() => DownloadImage(Obj));
public async void DownloadImage(Object obj)
{
    FormUrlEncodedContent formContent = GetFormContent(Obj);
    HttpResponseMessage Result = await client.PostAsync("URL", formContent).ConfigureAwait(false);
    byte[] Data = Result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
    StaticClass.Images[Obj.ID] = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(Data));
    formContent.Dispose();
    Result.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: if `DownloadImage` is being called on the same instance of whatever class this code is in, then there is no difference

Comment: @Jonesopolis Yep, that's the case.

Comment: Does anyone know when it would be appropriate to make a static HttpClient that is often reused? This post recommends making it so: https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: [HttpClient is fully thread-safe and reentrant](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/), so making it a static variable is actually the preferred way of interacting with it.

Comment: what is `temp`? And why isn't your `DownloadImage` `async`?

Comment: @AkashKava Sorry, fixed that. I removed and renamed things to make what I was trying to show clearer and missed some things.

Comment: As @AkashKava pointed out, your whole method should be marked with `async`, and return a `Task` (not `void`!).  As your method stands now, it won't even compile, since you can't use `await` in a non-async method. Also, calling `Result` on an async task without `await`, to try and invoke it synchronously, is a good way to deadlock things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**

Since you are not using `async` version and you are calling `ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result` you will most likely end up in deadlocks.

**Recommended**

Following is the most recommended way,

```
static HttpClient client = new HttpClient ();

public async Task DownloadImage(Object obj)
{
    using(FormUrlEncodedContent formContent = GetFormContent(Obj)) {
       using(HttpResponseMessage Result = await 
           client.PostAsync("URL", formContent)
           .ConfigureAwait(false)){
              byte[] Data = await Result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
              StaticClass.Images[Obj.ID] = ImageSource.FromStream(
                   () => new MemoryStream(Data));
        }
    }

}
```

Also don't call `Dispose`, use `using` block, `Dispose` will not be executed if an exception is thrown, `using` block will properly `Dispose` even in case of exception.

As long as, all disposables are wrapped in `using` and `async await` are used properly, `HttpClient` will perform best with single static instance.

Answer (score 0):

HttpClient is intented by microsoft to be used as  a static object. Even if the time to instatiate it every time is trivial, because other issues could arise.
his link contains a simple implementation :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client .

Since you will be using the client in more more cases than simple getting an image I would suggest a class with static methods (async if you may) for get/post/put/delete where you would inserting method names and objects dynamically.